# Codeigniter base url issue with www

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, base-url

I have declared the base url as $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';.

But the issue is if someone try to access my website with  'http://www.example.com/'; , css/ js functions are not working.

If I change the base url to 'http://www.example.com/' , users cannot access with 'http://example.com/'.

I am using codeigniter 3.0.3 . This is an issue with a website which is already online.

CSS - assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

JS - ">

. btw , ajax request are also failed.When I try to access an ajax function the bellow error showing on console –

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/Dynamic/home/normal/4. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

css error

Font from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: explain your code more add css/js path used its not clear

Comment: CSS - <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> JS - <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js');?>"></script>  . btw , ajax request are also failed

Comment: add your folder structure and the comment in the question or you can check in view source of the page are they showing up correct ??

Comment: make your base url() = www.example.com

Comment: Yes it is. Site is working without errors with that.but if I access my website without 'www' those errors are happening

Comment: yes please accept the answer i am adding

Answer (score 3):

I think the following code-block shows the best way to configure the base_url in Codeigniter :

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

And I strongly believe that this will solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your base url from

<strike>$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';</strike>

to

$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';

Reason:www and non-www website url are considered as different website so it gives the error of

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Better way is the add code in htaccess to convert non-www to www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope this explain the reason of change...

Answer (score 0):

Define baseUrl like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'stackoverflow.com/';
```

and `.htaccess` should be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

> > **As well as make sure URL helper is loaded.**

Comment: @HashKanchana Check this out